# Efficient method of using the previous row value based on the condition

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe as below.

```
df = [['A',1],
        ['A',1],
        ['A',0],
        ['A',0],
        ['A',5],
        ['B',0],
        ['B',0],
        ['B',1],
        ['B',1]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['flag', 'C'])
df
```

Create a new var E where,

1)for 1st row of each group of flag, 'E' = 'C'

2)if C >= previous row of E, then E = C else E = previous row E

Below is my expected output:

```
  flag  C  E
0    A  1  1
1    A  1  1
2    A  0  1
3    A  0  1
4    A  5  5
5    B  0  0
6    B  0  0
7    B  1  1
8    B  1  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in plain python, just applying the rules you defined.

```
df = [['A',1],
        ['A',1],
        ['A',0],
        ['A',0],
        ['A',5],
        ['B',0],
        ['B',0],
        ['B',1],
        ['B',1]]

last_flag = ''
last_e = 0
new_list = []
for flag, c in df:
    if flag == last_flag and c < last_e:
        e = last_e
    else:
        e = c
    last_flag = flag
    last_e = e
    new_list.append([flag, c, e])

print(new_list)
```

Comment: I want to do this on dataframe.

Comment: You can create a dataframe with the newly created list.